# Samsung Galaxy Buds disconnect from PC often

Tags: earbuds

When I use my earbuds on my PC they keep disconnecting every 5-6 seconds or so, sometimes longer, maybe a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is some kind of conflict between the Galaxy Buds Pro and my Bluetooth transmitter-receiver Avantree Oasis PLUS that is connected to my TV.

The Buds were connected to my PC while the TV was on and so the Avantree transmitter was also on. The transmitter would connect to **any** Bluetooth device that is in pair-mode. This is because the device has no screen so you can not select the device you want it to connect to. This works very well with all kinds of Bluetooth headphones, except Galaxy Buds Pro. For some reason **the Buds advertise themselves as always in pair-mode**, probably to support the feature to automatically connect to Samsung phones. Because of this, Avantree will connect to them and the Buds will disconnect from the original source, the PC.

I have not found a **solution** for this, except turning off Avantree transmitter.